# Inhouse App installs without provisioning profile on device

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I wrote an app signed with enterprise distribution certificate(inhouse) and ipa hosted on a website. When I try to install this App from there on device that doesn't have valid Enterprise Distribution Profile App installs fine which also installs that provisioning profile in the settings -> general -> profiles -> InhouseProvisioningprofile which was empty earlier. Why does it happen ? 
My understanding was App wouldn't install/run on device that doesn't have valid provisioning profile installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enterprise apps can be run on any device.  No prior provisioning is necessary.  If you are looking to restrict access to your app you need to find a way restrict who downloads it or which devices download it using certificates.